# App Script: delete n rows, leave 1 in a loop

Tags: loops, google-apps-script

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a loop in google sheets which would delete 3 rows and keep 1, again delete next 3 and keep forth one. Like this:

ROW 1
<strike>ROW 2</strike>
<strike>ROW 3</strike>
<strike>ROW 4</strike>
ROW 5
<strike>ROW 6</strike>
<strike>ROW 7</strike>
<strike>ROW 8</strike>

and so on...

I'm a beginner and totally stuck with it, still I tried to contribute by looking through search and google sheets reference. What I managed to find out is that when a row is deleted from a sheet, the following rows get renumbered as script continuous to run, so I assume I need to **start the loop from the end**. My initial attempt:

```
function myFunction() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var values = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();

for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sheet.deleteRow(); // here I'm totally stuck, how to delete 
                       // say 3 last and keep 4th from the bottom??
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below function

```
function deleteRows() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var values = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var k = -3;
  for (var i = values.length; i > 0; i--) {
      Logger.log(i)
      if(k % 4 != 0){
        sheet.deleteRow(i)
      }
      k++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be not working, looks like the script is running but nothing is actually happening. Your solution is interesting and taught me a lot.

Comment: I have tested it..it works...if needed you can share the copy of spreadsheet to debug more

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could take a look at it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YSUA313kjWaHfXjac5uWRKUgQguHIUuYjkdcDl_qVyI/edit?usp=sharing
All I get is the following info: "Running function deleteRows...Cancel | Dismiss"

Comment: It is working...you need to grant access before the first run....a new pop up window will appear asking for your authorization

Comment: OK looks like it works somehow - THANK YOU!

I have a question: Could you explain why you used   var k = -3; and not 0?

I love the way you figured out this line - so clever! if(k % 4 != 0)